# Why did the cluster cannot be still running when one ConfigNode and DataNode went down in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currenting using cluster version of Apache IoTDB with configuration of 3 ConfigNodes and 3 DataNodes, and I have the servers IoTDB 1-3. When I turn off the ConfigNode and DataNode of servers IoTDB 1, the cluster cannot be used. IoTDB 1 is the first node with `cn_internal_port` equals `10710`, and `cn_consensus_port` equals `10720`. The error message is `Msg: 301: Execute FragmentInstance failed: Raft Server is redoing Raft Log and cannot serve read requests now. Please try read later: org.apache.ratis.protocol.exceptions.ReadIndexException`. Does anyone know how to keep the cluster still running when one port is down?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show variables` command in Apache IoTDB to see if your `SchemaRegion` setting uses strong-consistent protocol. If so, you need to set the number of `DataRegion` copies to be 2, and the number of `SchemaRegion` copies to be 3. Then, your IoTDB cluster can still be running if one single node is down.